# Realm instances not closing on Activity#onDestroy

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, realm

I'm following the [realm documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/) to manage realm instances, on every activity I use the same pattern
OnDestroy's if always return that Realm is opened, and when I open the next activty the local Instance count returns the number of RealmInstances that had been opened

**For example:**

`SplashActivity#onCreate` -> Local Instance Count = 1

`FirstActivitiy#onCreate` -> Local Instance Count = 2

`SecondActivity#onCreate` -> Local Instance Count = 3

And it keeps increasing on every `Activity`. Anyone knows why realm instance for that activity is not closed on `onDestroy`?

I even tried to set realm as `null` after closing it, but it doesn't change the instance counter.

This is my code I used for testing:

```
 protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.splash_activity);
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
 }

 protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.e(TAG, "ON DESTROY");
    realm.close();
    if (realm.isClosed()) {
        Log.e(TAG, "REALM IS CLOSED");
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "REALM IS OPENED");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you call `finish()` on said activities?

Comment: Yeah I always call finish(). Ondestroy is called but Realm instance is opened

Answer (score 0):

As I guess, you open your new `Activity` without closing your current `Activity`.

If I am right, your current activity's `onDestroy` event won't work. You should `finish()` your current activity before open the new one or you can write your code another activity event. Because closing an activity could cause a problem for future cases. Maybe this could help you to find another activity event:
[Android Activity LifeCycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html)

Comment: I always call finish(). Ondestroy is called but Realm instance is opened